# How do I allow multiple predefined (enum) values for a request parameter?

Tags: java, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I want to receive multiple values for a query string parameter, e.g.:

```
/api/assets?category=light&category=heavy
```

while constraining the allowed values to a predefined set.

I already found [how to limit the allowed values](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/146#issuecomment-551345077), now how can I allow entering more than one value?

This is my current code:

```
public ApiRespSuccess<List<AssetApi>, ApiMetadataPagination> getAssets(
        @RequestParam @Parameter(schema=@Schema(description="param-desc", type="string", allowableValues= {"positioning", "energyReport"})) List<String> withExtFeature,
        @ParameterObject RequestPagination pagination) {
        // ...
```

If I remove the @Parameter annotation, swagger-ui shows an "Add item" button.

Comment: typically you'd do something like `?category=light,heavy`, not duplicating the request tag (as I'd imagine many apis would only end up seeing a `heavy` tag from that)

Comment: @Rogue Well, [Swagger PetStore findByStatus resource](https://petstore.swagger.io/#/pet/findPetsByStatus) generates a different cUrl.

Answer (score 2):

This is syntax how you can achieve your goal:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public SampleDTO getFile(@RequestParam @Parameter(array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(type = "string", allowableValues= {"positioning", "energyReport"})), description="param-desc") List<String> withExtFeature){
    return null;
}
```